# Eclipse doesn't generate class files since project clean

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ant

After cleaning eclipse workspace. The running or debugging doesn't generate class files. So I'm executing all time the same war.

I have to do an Ant build to have a new war. Someone can help me about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do the following steps:

Go to Project Menu and make sure Build Automatically is checked, Also you may need to check that  your installed JRE and Compilers match your Java version.

If that doesn't work for you, try to make sure that java builder is active in Project -> Properties -> Builders

Comment: Thank you very much